# How to copy a file from Win 10 PC to Android Device via USB using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, usb, transfer

From my Delphi app on Windows 10, I want to be able to transfer an android .apk file to the 'Internal Shared Storage\Download' folder on a USB attached Android Device.
It's actually a Datalogic Memor 1, but could be anything.

The Android device has file transfer enabled, and I can browse to the Download folder using Windows File Explorer and copy the file manually this way, but I can't find a way to do it from code.

When using TFile.Copy I always get 'The specified path was not found' but I don't know what path name I should be using and I suspect this is the wrong way to do it anyway.

I have looked into ADB but the device must be in debug mode for this to work so this is not an option.

It seems to me that this should be a fairly common thing to want to do.
How does the Window File Explorer do it?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Actually, this is _not_ a common thing to do. This kind of thing has all kinds of security-related issues. File transfer programs like Windows explorer use technology that is not easily accessible to use mere-mortals: specifically Samba.

Comment: This seems to be a job for [Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro).

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I have tried SHBrowseForFolder in shell32.dll and can browse to the folder on the device but it doesn't seem to return the path when selected. 
As I only need this to 'side load' an app on the device, I may come back to this later when time allows.
All other data transfer is done over the Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used the Portable library from https://www.winsoft.sk/portable.htm
Portable 2.0, Copyright (c) 2017-2021 WINSOFT

which uses the Microsoft Windows Portable Devices API
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/wpd-application-programming-interface

This is used to detect USB Mobile devices (Android etc.), transfer files to and from them etc. and it works extremely well.
It can also be used with legacy Windows CE devices.